# Is it right choice to choose ionic2 for production?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am working with ionic1 and angularjs1 now we are planning to create our new applications with ionic2 is it right choice?? because I have following Queries

- I know angular2 is Different from angularjs1 what about ionic1 and ionic2 ?
- Is there enough ionic2 support available ?
- Can we work with Less typescript knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to answer all of the three questions, would require a lot of time and would probably lead to more questions. What I can tell you is that:

- Ionic2 has support for Angular2, which is in your advantage;
- Structure of Ionic2 project is better
- You have totally different navigation than from Ionic1.
- The Ionic2 support will get better from day to day, so I wouldn't worry about that
- Typescript is pretty easy once you get hang of it, I would definitely give it a try.

Also, if you consider building hybrid apps, you can check out [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply , It could be the answer